# Finding frequency function and E(W) - probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

you have 7 keys in your pocket, one of which opens your front door. You sample then with replacement until you get in. Let W be the number of tries it takes. Find the frequency function of W and find E(W)

how do i do this? A step by step would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I won't give a step by step, but look up the Geometric Distribution and how it is used. That should get you on the right track.